# Unable to render text in arabic using React-pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am trying to display Arabic text in pdf using react-pdf but it shows un-appropriate text

Following is the text in png that I have tried to show in Arabic and English but only English letters are displayed but not the Arabic text.

[image]

And Following is the small snippet which I have used for setting the font family

```
import FontBold from '@assets/fonts/Inter/Inter-Bold.ttf';

import {styles} from './styles';

Font.register({
  family: 'Inter',
  fonts: [
    {
      src: FontRegular,
    },
    {
      src: FontMedium,
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
    {
      src: FontSemiBold,
      fontWeight: 600,
    },
    {
      src: FontBold,
      fontWeight: 700,
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many fonts do not have arabic characters and in your case that is not going to be possible without changing to another font, or modifications.

https://github.com/rsms/inter/issues/358

> Do you have any plans for supporting other languages in the typeface especially Arabic ?!

> Nope! Thanks for asking. It would be cool if someone familiar with Arabic script would take this on as a separate project :–)

read also https://github.com/rsms/inter/issues/391

which suggests using https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts

**Later edit**
Most recently suggests a means to apply two fonts by ranges see
https://github.com/rsms/inter/issues/391#issuecomment-1475339407

Comment: Thanks!, I have changed the fonts, it is now showing the text in Arabic but some of the use cases are not correct

example 

Following is the Actual text that needs to show is
 2020 اناس فاحاد
whereas the text that is rendered on the screen is اناس فاحاد 0002, The digits are flipped

Comment: I mean to say that when I am showing the text in Arabic, then there are numbers that are flipped when showing it to pdf for example if the number is 2000 then after rendering in pdf, the digits get flipped to 0002, it is only affecting the digits not the Arabic words